# No XML readers work!

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read an XML file with my C# application. I've tried many things and every time I try to use XmlReader or XmlTextReader, nothing works. It simply doesn't recognize any functions from the object I just created. I've tried the following with both XmlReader and XmlText Reader:

```
XmlReader reader = new XmlReader();
```

OR

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
```

When I try to use reader.Read() it simply returns an error acting like reader doesn't exist.
I'm a bit out of options as I don't understand XPath and these are what's left when it comes to reading XML as far as I understand it.

Comment: Exactly what went wrong with `XmlReader.Create`?

Comment: You posted code that doesn't actually fail.  And didn't describe the failure, "an error" is meaningless.  Post real code, real exception message, real stack trace.

Comment: Alternatively, we could close this as  "not a real question"

Comment: My apologies, I thought I was specific enough. When I use "reader.Read()" I get "Error: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration", and "Error: The type or namespace name 'reader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: My crystal ball whispered: "You have to write code in a method".

Comment: Sorry, I'm a C# newbie and I don't understand that terminology. Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Makes the smallest possible repro and post it here (like static void Main(){ XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);}). So far it looks likle you have syntax errors in your code somewhere else.

Comment: namespace SyntaxHilighter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("path");
        reader.Read();
    }
}
Note that I don't actually intend to use it that way, but simply as a test, it returns the errors I posted above. Also, sorry for the terrible formatting in comments...

Comment: +10 to Hans' crystall ball prediction - you are writing code outside of a method - update your question with this code instead of putting it to comments.

Comment: @Hans, why don't you use your powers to pick winning lottery numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the namespace at the top of your source file?

```
using System.Xml;
```

Answer (score -1):

XmlReader is an abstract class. Try XmlTextReader instead.

Comment: -1: No, don't use `new XmlTextReader()`. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead. Since .NET 2.0.

Comment: So, I wouldn't include the path in XmlReader.Create() ?
I've tried that before.